# ReferenceError: window is not defined when run SSR in angular 9

Tags: server-side-rendering

Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4000
{ Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: window is not defined
ReferenceError: window is not defined
at new DefaultLayoutComponent (D:\Rakesh Project\CTM\MetatagCTMTest\dist\web\server\main.js:1:2704879)
at NodeInjectorFactory.DefaultLayoutComponent_Factory [as factory] (D:\Rakesh Project\CTM\MetatagCTMTest\dist\web\server\main.js:1:2705335)
at getNodeInjectable (D:\Rakesh Project\CTM\MetatagCTMTest\dist\web\server\main.js:1:3080070)

Comment: Found any solution ?